# function to remove empty <p> removes <p>'s with content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

ive made a function that should remove a p-element if it doesnt have any content or has a br inside itself, when leaving after contenteditable. The problem is that it removes an li that HAS content aswell when .blur() !?
Im going nuts because im sure it worked 10min ago.........

here's the function:

```
$('p').live('blur', function() {
localStorage.setItem('todo', listan.innerHTML);
color();

if ($(this).html() == "" || "<br>")
{
  console.log($(this).html());
  $(this).parent().remove();
  localStorage.setItem('todo', listan.innerHTML);
}
});
```

the list ("listan") looks like this:

```
<ul ID="listan">
      <li><p contenteditable="true" class="thing">something</p><input type="button" value="ta bort" class="delete"></li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: oh and if i add a console.log($(this).html()); in the if-statement, it alert me with the actual content ("something" for example)

Comment: Well, your code is `$(this).parent().remove();`, which means that you're selecting the parent of the P element which is a LI element. If you want to remove the P element only, do: `$(this).remove();` instead.

Comment: its the li i want to remove if the p is empty, sorry for beeing unclear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `.parent()` from the code, since the parent element of "blurring" `p` is `li`. Also check your if statement.

```
$('p').live('blur', function() {
    localStorage.setItem('todo', listan.innerHTML);
    color();

    var html = $(this).html();
    if (html == "" || html == "<br>") {
        console.log($(this).html());
        $(this).remove();
        localStorage.setItem('todo', listan.innerHTML);
    }
});​
```

Comment: +1 Did'nt see your answer and did'nt realise I was a little late to the party !

Comment: its the li i want to remove if the p is empty, sorry for beeing unclear.

Comment: but the if-statement fixed it! :) god i must be tired... :P

Answer (score 1):

```
if( $(this).html() == "" || "<br>")
```

What this line is saying is "if the html is empty, or if `<br>` is something".

So it's always true, so no matter what the content is it gets removed.

Try this:

```
if( $(this).html().replace(/\s|<br ?\/?>/) == "")
```

This will strip out spaces (most importantly leading and trailing) and line breaks and see if the result is empty.

Comment: ahh! ofc.. *facepalm*
can u explain what replace(/\s|<br ?\/?>/) == "") means? I get what it does but doesnt understand the (/\s|<br ?\/?>/ == "") part
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var html = $(this).html();
if (html == "" || html == "<br>") {....do stuff....}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CSS?

```
p:empty {
    display: none 
}
```